# Youtube iFrame API not working on microsoft edge

Tags: youtube-api, microsoft-edge

I'm implementing a modal with youtube iframe api but i can't make it work on microsoft edge.. i have a snippet to check if someone can help me with this `http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/D2Pnq`

It throws `Object doesn't support property or method 'playVideo'`

Comment: Are you using it with mobile environments?

Comment: Umm... i quite don't know what are mobile environments.. you mean watch the page on a mobile? if that's so.. no.